# jquery пробежать по всем дочерним элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне необходимо найти все элементы с классом `incorrect`, когда у меня есть `this` объекта одного из `input` в таблице (не важно какого), после этого по набору этих полей мне надо пробежать и посчитать их количество, если текст уникален то класс я удаляю.

Все инпуты для выборки имею класс `typeahead`

```
function ValidProduct(Obj,Metka){
    var Input = $(Obj);
    console.log("--",Input.closest('tbody').find('input.typeahead.incorrect').length);
    Input.closest('tbody').find('input.typeahead.incorrect').each(function(){
                console.log(this);
    });

}
```

И вот получается что `this` объект функции не учитывается в обходе. Что не так?

Comment: попробуйте  console.log($(this));

Comment: суть не в выводе а в том что он пропускает объект который был передан в функцию.

Comment: Нужно выложить html-код c таблицей

Comment: Не совсем понятно для чего вам такая строгая выборка. Тут вариантов может быть море. Во-первых выполните в консоли код 
$('input.typeahead.incorrect').each(function(){
                console.log(this);
    });

Comment: что значит _this объект функции не учитывается в обходе_?

Comment: Так попробуйте
function(element){
                console.log(element);
    }

Comment: Наванговал разметку https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/q9f2k7f6/ , проблема не наблюдается.

Comment: @Oma если `Obj` не появляется в `console.log(this);`, значит у него не стоят классы `typeahead` и `incorrect` (вместе!) или это не `input`

Comment: Ага между ними есть еще класс, который сгенерился автоматически.

Comment: @Oma - порядок перечисления названий классов в аттрибуте `class` значения не имеет. Пора добавить в вопрос html ис браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` принимает 2 аргумента. Первый как индекс, и второй как само значение (в данном случае - объект):

```
function ValidProduct(Obj, Metka) {
        var Input = $(Obj);

        console.log("--", Input
            .closest('tbody')
            .find('input.typeahead.incorrect')
            .length);

        Input
            .closest('tbody')
            .find('input.typeahead.incorrect')
            .each(function (index, object) {
                console.log(object);
            });
    }
```

Comment: второй параметр имеет то же самое значение что и `this` в данном случае